# Angular 2 how to put object array in to another object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

So I have `2 Arrays` (Always equal `index`) :

```
A: [
{name: Jhon1}
{name: Jhon2}
{name: Jhon3}
]

B: [
{lastName: Pom1}
{lastName: Pom2}
{lastName: Pom3}
]
```

Expected Result after merge  :

```
A: [
   {name: Jhon1, lastName: Pom1}
   {name: Jhon2, lastName: Pom2}
   {name: Jhon3, lastName: Pom3}
]
```

`Concat` method just merges the whole array in to one like this :

```
  A: [
    {name: Jhon1}
    {name: Jhon2}
    {name: Jhon3}
    {lastName: Pom1}
    {lastName: Pom2}
    {lastName: Pom3}
    ]
```

My own function that I am trying. Below there is two arrays: `this.prices` and `this.search.favoriteItems`, I want to merge then the same way as I described before :

```
showProducts(){
   for(let i of this.localStorageArray){
    let id = localStorage.getItem(i);
    this.search.getProductsById(id).subscribe
    ((data: any) => {
     this.prices.push(data.lowestPrices.Amazon);
     this.search.favoriteItems.push(data);  
   //something here to merge this.prices and this.search
    });

  }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.map()` with Object destrcuturing:

```js
let arr1 = [{name: 'Jhon1'}, {name: 'Jhon2'}, {name: 'Jhon3'}],
    arr2 = [{lastName: 'Pom1'}, {lastName: 'Pom2'}, {lastName: 'Pom3'}];

let zip = (a1, a2) => a1.map((o, i) => ({...o, ...a2[i]}));

console.log(zip(arr1, arr2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Also thank you for the CSS wrapper, didn't know you could do that !